# Render HTML file in VF page

Tags: apex

This is my content in HTML file

```
&lt;h1&gt;London&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;London is the capital city of England.&lt;/h3&gt;
```

I upload this file in attachment and query this file and I want to render this HTML file in visualforce page but VF page output shows me just

## London

London is the capital city of England.

This doesn't show me the h1 header and paragraph content.

```
<apex:page controller="htmlrendertest"  contentType="text/html" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!body}"> </apex:outputText> 
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class htmlrendertest {
    Public String body {get;set;}
    public htmlrendertest() {
        try {
            body = [SELECT Id, body FROM Attachment WHERE name = 'test.html'][0].body.tostring();
            body = body.replace('&lt;', '<');
            body = body.replace('&gt;', '>');
        } catch(exception e) {
            body = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Visualforce, by default, protects you from something called "[HTML injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Spoofing)". This is generally a good thing. However, if you want to disable this protection, and thus allow your HTML to be rendered as-is, you can do so with the `escape` attribute:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!body}" escape="false" />
```